# GCC ARM linker error - undefined reference to 'strcmp'

Tags: c, gcc, arm, std

I have a TIVA-C microcontroller project, compiled with arm-none-eabi-gcc and although I added string.h I'm getting 'undefined reference to strcmp' linker error. I'm using the precompiled toolchain:  gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3-20140805-linux.tar.bz2 from here: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download. My makefile switches:

```
# define flags
CFLAGS = -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp
CFLAGS +=-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall
CFLAGS += -pedantic -DPART_$(MCU) -c -I$(TIVAWARE_PATH)
CFLAGS += -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
LDFLAGS = -T $(LD_SCRIPT) --entry ResetISR --gc-sections
```

There were others with the same problem but they've the -nostd switch on in the LDFLAGS what I apparently don't have. I'm out of ideas now, so any tip would be great.

Comment: can you please show us the error message?

Comment: Give a test. Add just a reference to strcmp (Just declare the prototype of the function), and try to compile again. I want to check if the shared object of the libc will be dynamically linked. If not, then the standard C library is not correctly installed for your arm crosscompilation

Comment: me@sg:~/__PW__/projecttiva$ make
arm-none-eabi-ld -o build/a.out build/console.o build/cmdline.o build/uartstdio.o build/startup_gcc.o build/console_uart.o build/console_command.o build/board.o build/main.o -T TM4C123GH6PM.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections
build/cmdline.o: In function `CmdLineProcess':
/home/me/__PW__/projecttiva/src/cmdline.c:169: undefined reference to `strcmp'
make: *** [build/a.out] Error 1

Comment: @sestus: I commented out string.h and put int strcmp(const char * s1, const char * s2); on the top of the relevant source file. I've got the same error message. (I hope I interpreted your question correctly).

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. To me it seems that the linker cannot locate the libc shared object (for arm). Are you sure you installed it?

Comment: @JustGreg Are you writing your own linker script, and using ld directly ? If so you'll somehow have to link in the libc library. Or you can use `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to perform the linking instead of `arm-none-eabi-ld`.

Comment: @sestus: My toolchain is precompiled so I've just placed in /opt. I can see libc.a present in /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3/arm-none-eabi/lib

Comment: In my makefile, I'm using arm-none-eabi-ld with a linker script: $(OUTDIR)/a.out: $(OBJECTS)
 $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
, 

The linker script isprovided by TI. It doesn't contain link to libc, only memory sections.

Comment: Then use -gcc (or -g++) for linking, and it will work. You have to pass your flags differently - `-Wl,-T$(LD_SCRIPT),--entry=ResetISR,--gc-sections` (no spaces, comma separated, use -Wl to to introduce linker flags, there can be multiple -Wl).

Comment: @Freddie Chopin: In that case I use -gcc to link I have to modify my Makefile where I'm not really good at. Here is my Makefile and some tips would be really appreciated:

https://github.com/uctools/tiva-template/blob/master/Makefile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem happens because you use -ld for linking directly. As a multilib toolchain, arm-none-eabi has multiple variants of libc.a (which contains the function you need) and other standard libraries. -ld just cannot find the right libraries.

To solve your problem, modify your makefile in following places:

Replace:

```
# define flags
CFLAGS = -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp
CFLAGS +=-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall
CFLAGS += -pedantic -DPART_$(MCU) -c -I$(TIVAWARE_PATH)
CFLAGS += -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
LDFLAGS = -T $(LD_SCRIPT) --entry ResetISR --gc-sections
```

with:

```
# define flags
COREFLAGS = -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp
CFLAGS = -g $(COREFLAGS)
CFLAGS +=-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall
CFLAGS += -pedantic -DPART_$(MCU) -c -I$(TIVAWARE_PATH)
CFLAGS += -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
LDFLAGS = $(COREFLAGS) -T$(LD_SCRIPT) -Wl,--entry=ResetISR,--gc-sections
```

Replace:

```
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld
```

with:

```
LD = arm-none-eabi-g++
```

The idea is simple - to the linking stage you pass all the options that are relevant to the architecture (everything that starts with `-m`), and the options for linker are prefixed with `-Wl,`, multiple linker options can be concatenated with commas, without the need to repeat the `-Wl,` prefix. No prefix is needed for `-T`, `-L` and `-l`.

You can also check out my example ARM projects, which include a quite nice Makefile - I never had any library issues with that. On my website (link in profile) go to Download > ARM > Examples, and pick which one you like - there's no example for tiva, but the one for STM32F4 will be the closest match.

Comment: Freddie thank you for the detailed answer. I can compile&link my code now. Probably you mean LD = arm-none-eabi-gcc instead of LD = arm-none-eabi-g++, don't you? Anyways, I changed to that and the compiler/linker did not complain.

Comment: @JustGreg - You can use gcc or g++ for linking - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also, just a stylistic note, it's perhaps cleaner to read with newline escapes rather than repeatedly appending to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: @OllieFord - pure preference, I like `+=` more (;

Comment: @FreddieChopin Woah, okay. :)

Comment: ld doesnt know where the libraries are by default, gcc knows where it was spawned from and where to find those files.  gcc calls ld so ld still does the job, to use ld you simply have to supply the full path to those files.

Comment: @dwelch - it is possible to use ld directly, but what's the point? My arm-none-eabi toolchain has 11 variants of multilib (so 11 x libc.a, 11 x libm.a, etc,), is there any advantage in selecting the right one by hand? In my opinion - none...

Comment: gcc is a compiler not an assembler nor a linker, it simply leaves a bad taste to use it as a linker.  Unfortunately if you choose to use C or gcc libraries, it is certainly the easiest way with that toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using an embedded toolchain, it likely doesn't link to libc without you instructing it to. add `-lc` to your LDFLAGS to see if it solves the problem as this will at least attempt to link to libc.